# $_SESSION only setting when I log in twice

Tags: php

I have a log in page that will check your user and your password. If it is correct it should direct you to your user page, however I only get direcered to the user page when I enter the username and password twice. It does not set the `$_SESSION['user'];` immediatly. Why?

Here is the log in page(it is a seperate file that is called from another file that is called from index.php):

```
<?php

header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8');
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
<div id="login-form">
  <?php
$rop = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM admin_users");
// var_dump($rop);
if (isset($_POST['log-in'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['login']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        header("location:index.php?empty=Fill in all the fields");

    } else {

        $login  = smart($_POST['login']);
        $pass   = smart($_POST['password']);
        $select = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM `admin_users` WHERE `user` = '$login'");
        $user   = $select->num_rows;

        if ($user == 1) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $login;

            $x       = $select->fetch_assoc();
            $passh   = md5(md5($pass));
            $selects = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM `admin_users` WHERE user = '$login' AND pass = '$passh'");
            $users   = $selects->num_rows;
            if ($users == 1) {

                $_SESSION['pass'] = $passh;
                header('Refresh: 0; url=' . $base_url . 'user');
            } else {

                header("location:index.php?Invalid=Wrong username and/or password!");
            }
        } else {

            header("location:index.php?wrong=Wrong username and/or password!");
        }
    }
}
?>

  <form  method="POST"  name="login-form" onsubmit="return validateLogin()">
    <?php
if (@$_GET['empty'] == true) {
?>
     <center style='color: red;'><?php echo $_GET['empty'];?></center><br>
    <?php
} elseif (@$_GET['wrong'] == true) {
?>
     <center style='color: red;'><?php echo $_GET['wrong'];?></center><br>
    <?php
}
?>
   <p id="email-login" class="email">Email<span class="required">*</span><img src="ico/ic-mail.png" align="right" class="ic-mail"></p>
    <input id="email-login1" type="text" name="login">

    <p id="pwd-login" class="pwd">Password<span class="required">*</span><img src="ico/ic-lock.png" align="right" class="ic-lock"></p>
    <input id="pwd-login1" type="password" name="password">
    <a id="forgot" href="#" class="forgot">Forgot?</a>
    <button id="log-in" type="submit" name="log-in" class="loginb"><span style="cursor:pointer">login</span></button>

  </form>
</div>
```

Once I subbmit the username and password and if they are correct it gets directed to user/index.php where :

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('../inc/config.php');
include('includes/inc.php');
include('includes/users.inc.php');
include('includes/users.inc-view.php');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <link rel="icon" type="png" href="ico/logo.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200">
  </head>

  <body>
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
?>
   <div class="content">

      <div id="main_nav">
        <div class="menu_header">Hey, <?php echo $_SESSION['user'];?> [<a href="?logout">LOGOUT</a>]</div>
         <div class="menu_header">User</div>
         <a href="<?php echo $base_url;?>user/?users"><li>Add user details</li></a>
     </div>
      <?php
    if (file_exists($pagex)) {
        include($pagex);
    } else {
        echo "File:  <i>" . $pagex . "</i>  does not exist!";
    }
?>
   </div>
<?php
} else {
    include('includes/goback.php');
}
?>
 </body>

</html>
```

The code goes through the index page and there should be a $_SESSION set but there is not so it goes back to the first index.php where the login form is and once I log in again only then it works.

and here is user/incudes/goback.php:

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){

  header('Refresh: 0; url='.$base_url.'');

}else{
  header('Refresh: 0; url='.$base_url.'user');
}
```

this is probably badly asked by me so sorry but I can not understand why I can't set the session with the 1st try. And i have tried with cookeies as well still the same result. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to `session_start();` somehwere else as well?

thanks

Comment: yes, `session_start();` should be placed in your login php file, before saving somethings like `$_SESSION['user'] = $login;`

Comment: but I have tried to type session_start(); in the begining of the login.php still the same. You have to add session_start(); to the page top which you want to be redirected as well still no results.

Comment: Check your PHP log for "Headers already sent" warnings. If you see that, you haven't put `session_start()` in the correct place.

Comment: Agree with vnt Without a call to session_start() at your login script there is no way you can 'put' values in your $_SESSION

Comment: i just checked, there is no error like that. I know what you mean but there is not error like that.

Comment: yes, yes, yes. I know, the session_start() is at config.php and config.php is included in all of files so it should automaticly have a session started. But i have already tempered with adding only the session_start(); at the pages that i wish to use the session on only. It is frusturting :D